# Image Width not detecting % in Github Readme (HTML)

Tags: html, github, github-flavored-markdown, readme

I have spent a lot of time designing my GitHub readme.

`<img width="100%" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sabyasachi-Seal/Sabyasachi-Seal/ouput/action2.gif"/>`

Earlier, the pictures in the GitHub readme could be resized with the help of % values, with 100% meaning the full width of the page.

Recently, the % system is not working. Giving the % and not giving the % is not making any difference. Is there a workaournd?

Earlier: https://i.stack.imgur.com/78M6W.png

Now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlWac.png

Profile Link: https://github.com/Sabyasachi-Seal

Comment: You can't use `%` in the width or height attribute, instead define a style attribute and assign those values to it.

Answer (score 0):

`<p><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sabyasachi-Seal/Sabyasachi-Seal/ouput/action2.gif" width="100%" height="100%"/></p>`

works for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32640839)